# Can't read file in VHDL with GHDL

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

This doesn't work. Error seems to appear whenever I change variable line_content : string(1 to 4) to string(1 to 20).

It says that there is an assertion failure: string read failure.
assertion failed.
simulation failed.

```
LIBRARY ieee; 
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use STD.textio.all; 

ENTITY read_file IS
END read_file;

ARCHITECTURE beha OF read_file IS 

BEGIN
-- Read process
    process 
      file file_pointer : text;
      variable line_content : string(1 to 20);
      variable line_num : line;

    begin
        --Open the file read.txt from the specified location for reading(READ_MODE).
      file_open(file_pointer,"1.txt",READ_MODE);    
      while not endfile(file_pointer) loop --till the end of file is reached continue.
        readline (file_pointer,line_num);  --Read the whole line from the file
        --Read the contents of the line from  the file into a variable.
        READ (line_num,line_content); 
            report line_content;
      end loop;
      file_close(file_pointer);  --after reading all the lines close the file.  
        wait;
    end process;
end beha;
```

Comment: These errors appear to be from ghdl. To replicate the problem supply enough line values from 1.txt for the problem to show up. There is a requirement that the the line_num string value has an element for each position of the string line_content. An easy solution would be to fill lines in file 1.txt with white space. A hard solution would create a string access type whose length is allocated line_num.all'length after the readline use it as a temporary holder for the READ and copy it's contents to line_content (with appropriate fill/truncate) then deallocate (rinse) and repeat.

Comment: I tested your process and it works for 1.txt lines at least line_content length.

Comment: thank you! I happened to find out that the cause of the problem was the size of the text it is reading. The num of characters to be read should be the same with what was declared on the code.